# Is there any format in SAS that displays datetime without a T separator?

Tags: sas

I need a format that displays datetime data without T in between separating the date and time parts. Instead I need (: a colon) to separate the date and time parts in a datetime data.

Is there a format for this type?

Or do I have to create a format using proc format PICTURE?

Comment: You're getting back an [ISO 8601 timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  I don't know much about SAS but if nothing else, you're totally getting a legitimate and valid and real-world applicable timestamp.

Comment: There is no such system format using colon to separate the date and time parts. you may need to define it yourself.

Comment: The normal DATETIME format does NOT add a T and does use a colon.  `19MAY2022:21:34:01`. What format are you currently using?

Comment: Same question as this: